# SharePoint 2013 Search is not returning result

Tags: content-search-web-part, searchserviceapplication

We are using SharePoint 2013 on-premises enterprise version. The search function on our site not returning results and ending up with no resource found. Before a week it was working fine but now it's not.
   Below are the errors I found in central admin under search service administration. 
   [image]

if I click "content resource" or any other option on the left panel am getting the error
[image: .]

Answer (score 0):

Check if TLS 1.1 and TLS 1.2 are installed on the server. If they are, try to re enable them to open a connection. This issue is usually caused because there is no SSL Protocol available on the server to communicate with sharepoint search servers.